# InDesign scripting, get the items selected in a panel

Tags: javascript, scripting, adobe-indesign

I am working on a Javascript that searches for certain "paragraph styles" inside InDesign, the way I want to accomplish that is by creating an array of 'paragraph styles' which are selected in the 'paragraph styles panel', is there a way I can reference all the selected Styles inside the UI of a Panel?

Comment: Before you do any scripting, it looks like you are trying to do something which is already in InDesign or your question is unclear. Are you trying to generate a paragraph style through the script? Paragraph styles are an array already, do you need a separate group? It also helps if you post what you tried so far.

Comment: I want to move the paragraphs with 'certain' styles to separate layers, I did already the script by searching for styles starting with certain prefix name, but it would be much more convenient to do it via style selection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

However a raw answer is NO.
UI panel's selections are not scriptable (doesnt exist in Object Model)

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure what are you trying to do, but provided you have CC 2014 and up you will need to look at Adobe CEP. This uses node.js/io.js to build custom pallets. Here is a link:

https://github.com/Adobe-CEP/CEP-Resources/wiki/CEP-6-HTML-Extension-Cookbook-for-CC-2015

Answer (score 0):

I confirm. I did some experimentations thinking that we can get something out of the selection we could introspect (i.e. copying selected links to a location for example). However any of the attemps i explored thrown a dialog. So it's not a way to go.
Probably the only solution is low level code. Unless I am wrong.
Loic

Answer (score -1):

app.activeDocument.paragraphStyles this will give all the paragraphstyles in the document through indesign script(.jsx).get it using csinterface.evalscript()

Comment: That gives a list of all styles. The question asks for selected only.